# Why does switch match a different type in below code sample in golang

Tags: go, switch-statement

Link:
https://play.golang.org/p/69I8PAuoAV

Extract:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Stringer interface {
    String() string
}

type fakeString struct {
    content string
}

// function used to implement the Stringer interface
func (s *fakeString) String() string {
    return s.content
}

func printString(value interface{}) {
    switch str := value.(type) {
    case string:
        fmt.Println(str)
    case Stringer:
        fmt.Println(str.String())
    }
}

func main() {
    s := &fakeString{"Ceci n'est pas un string"}
    printString(s)
    printString("Hello, Gophers")

}
```

The `printString(s)` function call when reaching case matches the `case Stringer` part.
`s` is of type `*fakeString` not `Stringer`.
Why does it match `Stringer`.

I did a `fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(str))` and it confirmed the type as `*main.fakeString`

Comment: `fakeString` type isn't equivalent to `string`, but it does implement `Stringer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **interface satisfaction** in golang.

There are two kinds of type in golang: *interface type* and *concrete type*.

- `concrete type` works exactly as you expected in `switch`: the variable is an instance of the given type
- `interface type` on the other hand works differently, it checks if the variable **satisfies** the interface.

Hum, **safisfies**? How does it work?

> **A (concrete) type satisfies an interface if it possesses all the methods the interface requires.**
>
> -- the golang programming language

In the case, `Stringer` is an interface, declaring only one method: `String() string`. And `fakeString` satisfies it by having its own `String() string` method.

Two things to note however:

1. concrete type can have many other methods, it still satisfies the interface if it possesses all methods declared in interface
2. the methods order does not matter, all that matters is the set of methods.

Comment: Thanks. It took some time for me to understand that `func (s *fakeString) String() string` == `fakeString` implementing `Stringer`. It seemed just a function that take `s` of type `*fakeString` as input.

Comment: @Ivan Unlike other language(like Java), golang interface and its implementation does not have explicit code declaration, the *satisfies check* runs behind the scene. This can be confusing for starters!

Answer (score 4):

In Go to satisfy an interface all you have to do is implement the methods of that interface nothing else. In this case to have a behavior as a **Stringer** you have to implement `String() string`, so the type fakeString behaves as a **Stringer** because implement that method; in terms of OOP we use interfaces just to define behavior not types or values. So you may be implementing Go interfaces all day without knowing, but not big deal, it only matters when you have to satisfy behaviors.

Actually in a real project you may want to add a `default` case to your switch in the method `printString`, to detect when the interface{} is something else, like this:

```
func printString(value interface{}) {
    switch str := value.(type) {
    case string:
        fmt.Println("string", str)
    case Stringer:
        fmt.Println("Stringer", str.String())
    default:
        fmt.Printf("unexpected type: %T value: '%v'", str, str)
    }
}

// main:
printString(2)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/pmxSXfUu4e